# How to check an existence of entry in RapidMiner repository to prevent overwriting?

Tags: repository, rapidminer

I have a part of RapidMiner process within `Loop URL` operator which reads a text file from disk (`Read Document`) and saves it into RapdiMiner repository (`Store`) under a name %{loop_url}.txt defined by a macro within `Loop URL`.

It may happen that the repository entry with this name already exists, so I don't want to overwrite it.

How do I check that the entry with a given name already exists in RapdiMiner repository and prevent overwriting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `Handle Exception` operator. Inside the `try` section you could try to retrieve the named repository entry you are about to write. If this succeeds you could write the new entry with a new name. If the `try` fails, the `catch` section would be executed and you could write your repository entry in the normal way.